# How to apply multiprocessing in high dimension array of python?(Issues never explained)

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing

We know that  multiprocessing package in python can achieve Parallel Computing.
But the tutorial only descripe the one dimensinal array.
Such as:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

But ,if X is a Three-dimensional array or even higher,and we pass to the function f is not each value of X (as  X[i,j,k],that is each value).
And I want to ask, if I want to pass the slice of the two-dimensional,such as X[i,j,:](which is the Portion of the array), how to write the function f? and How to apply multiprocessing.

Of course,we can do it in this way:

```
def f(x):
    #do something
    #and the x is One-dimensional array
    #the return value is 
    return y
Y=np.zeros((X.shape[0],X.shape[1]))
for i in range(0,X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,X.shape[1]):
        Y[i,j]=f(X[i,:])
```

but in this way ,that is too slow,especially for  very larger array.
So ,I want to ask ,how to achieve the function and  multiprocess in python?
Or Or is there another way?

Comment: if you use `numpy` then you should try to use function built-in in `numpy` without using `for`-loops which only slow down all code.

Comment: `multiprocessing` doesn't use array but list with arguments - `p.map(f, [arg1, arg2, arg3])` - and runs in separated processes `f(arg1)`, `f(arg2)`, `f(arg3)`. If you use list with arrays - `p.map(f, [array1, array2, array3])` - then it will run in separated processes `f(array1)`, `f(array2)`, `f(array3)`

Comment: How to pass  a array slice directly in Pool.map and design the function?

Comment: if you want to use `map()` then you have to first create list with all slices. [ X[0,:], X[1,:], X[2,:] ]` - `p.map( f,  [ X[0,:], X[1,:], X[2,:] ] )` - if you want slide only on first dimention then it should work also `p.map( f,  X )` because it should will tread `X` as list of [ X[0,:], X[1,:], X[2,:] ]`. For more dimentions it make problem. Eventually you can send bigger arrays to multiprocess and evey multiprocess may use own `Pool` to run with smaller arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`map()` expects list of aguments for `f()`

```
 results = p.map(f, [arg1, arg2, arg3])
```

and it will run in separated processes `f(arg1)`, `f(arg2)`, `f(arg3)`

You can use list of slices to work with rows

```
 results = p.map(f, [X[0,:], X[1,:], X[2,:]])
```

or simpler

```
 results = p.map(f, [X[0], X[1], X[2]])
```

xbut for first dimention you can use directly

```
 results = p.map(f, X)
```

and it will run `f()` with every row separatelly - `f(X[0])`, `f(X[1])`, `f(X[2]).

But you can do the same without multiprocessing

```
 results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, X)
```

Eventually with `-1` if it is 2D array

```
 results = np.apply_along_axis(f, -1, X)
```

if you want to run in columns

```
 results = p.map(f, [X[:,i] for i in range(X.shape[1])])
```

or

```
 results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, X)
```

---

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def f(arr):
    result = sum(arr)
    #print(f'f({arr}) = {result}')
    return result

X = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [4,5,6,7],
    [7,8,9,0]
])

print('--- rows ---')

with Pool(2) as p:
#    results = p.map(f, [X[0,:], X[1,:], X[2,:]])
#    results = p.map(f, [X[0], X[1], X[2]])
#    results = p.map(f, [X[i,:] for i in range(X.shape[0])])
#    results = p.map(f, [X[i] for i in range(X.shape[0])])
    results = p.map(f, X)
    print(results)

#results = np.apply_along_axis(f, -1, X)
results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, X)
print(results)

print('--- cols ---')

with Pool(2) as p:
    results = p.map(f, [X[:,i] for i in range(X.shape[1])])
    print(results)

results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, X)
print(results)
```

---

For more dimensions it may need `for`-loop (or nested loops)

```
with Pool(2) as p:
    all_results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        results = p.map(f, X[i])
        all_results.append(results)
    print(all_results)
```

or simply

```
results = np.apply_along_axis(f, -1, X)
```

---

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def f(arr):
    result = sum(arr)
    #print(f'f({arr}) = {result}')
    return result

X = np.array([
    [ [1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4] ],
    [ [4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7] ],
    [ [7,8,9,0],[7,8,9,0],[7,8,9,0] ],
])

print('--- rows ---')

with Pool(2) as p:
    all_results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        results = p.map(f, X[i])
        all_results.append(results)
    print(all_results)

#results = np.apply_along_axis(f, -1, X)
results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 2, X)
print(results)

print('--- cols ---')

with Pool(2) as p:
    all_results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        results = p.map(f, X[:,i]) # X[:,i].T
        all_results.append(results)
    print(all_results)

results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, X)
print(results)

print('--- depth ---')

with Pool(2) as p:
    all_results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[2]):
        results = p.map(f, X[:,:,i])
        all_results.append(results)
    print(all_results)

results = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, X)
print(results)
```